# Increase timeout on AWS ECS Fargate Rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a Fast API deployed to ECS Fargate and every request times out after 20 seconds, there is no Load Balancer set up or anything. But I can't find an easy way for increasing the timeout.

Locally when I run that same service it doesn't timeout.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So there isn't a load balancer, but are you using other services like AWS API Gateway or CloudFront? If so you need to look at the timeout values there. If not, then timeout would be entirely controlled by your Fast API configuration and you may need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265343/python-fastapi-server-how-to-extend-connection-timeout Also, when it works locally, are you running the same docker image locally, or are you running it locally via some other method?